# Como passar parâmetros para funções callback em eventos HTML com javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

Olá, boa noite, estou com problema com funções callback em javascript e preciso de ajuda.

As seguintes linhas abaixo tratam de linhas em uma tabela HTML, caso o elemento presente em cell2 seja um elemento composto, eu adiciono um botão + para que possa ser expandido pelo usuário e utilizo a função callback de click.

Este código está dentro de um laço, que vai criando as linhas e armazenando em firstRow.

O que eu quero é que o dado de firstRow dentro da callback represente o momento em que ele foi criado.

Mas não é isso que está acontecendo, independente em qual ícone que eu clico o valor firstRow sempre contém o último elemento da iteração.

Como eu faço para passar algum parâmetro para a função callback?

```
firstRow.setAttribute("class", "clickable");
    firstRow.setAttribute("data-toggle", "collapse");
    firstRow.setAttribute("data-target", ".row"+objeto.idtab);
    firstRow.setAttribute("id", "linha_"+objeto.idtab);
    cell2.innerHTML = "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i><div id='variableToggle_"+objeto.idtab+"'>";
    cell1.innerHTML = objeto.Nome;
    cell2.addEventListener("click", function(offset, firstRow){
        if(show){
            show = false;
            cell2.innerHTML = "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i><div id='variableToggle_"+objeto.idtab+"'>"
            var i = finalRow.rowIndex;
            while(i > firstRow.rowIndex){
                table.deleteRow(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
        else{
            finalRow = insertVariableFields(objeto.idtab, ref, firstRow);
            show = true;
            cell2.innerHTML = "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></i><div id='variableToggle_"+objeto.idtab+"'>"

        }
        console.log('abriu');
    });
```

Comment: Olá Jacons! Dá uma olhada à outra pergunta que linkei. Se não conseguires implementar diz que dou mais uma ajuda aqui nos comentários.

Comment: Olá, realmente foi útil o link, eu achava que era algum problema com o closure mas não estava encontrando uma alternativa, o exemplo 2 da resposta foi útil pra mim, obrigado.

Comment: Ótimo! Até breve!